# primary key must be unique when extending table

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add extend user model. I keep getting this error: `Primary key is not unique`.

```
class UserExtended(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,parent_link=True,primary_key=True)
```

If I remove `primary_key=True` then I get the error `instance.userextended.id does not exists` well, of course it doesn't since now I dont have id.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

In **models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class UserExtended(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # Then you can also add fields like these to extended model
    profilepic = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/users/%Y/%m/%d/', null=True, blank=True)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True, blank=True)
    about = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(null=True,blank=True)


    def __str__(self):  
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserExtended.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.userextended.save()
```

Now, whenever a new user is created, a extended record for that user will be created automatically.

Also, if a user record is saved, then it will automatically be updated in extended record.

Comment: @JamAndJammies Just try this and if it doesn't work, let me know I will provide you a detailed solution to this.

Comment: Do you have data in your database?

Comment: oops sorry accidentally deleted my last comment. same error as above... yes did a dump, i have data in the database

Comment: Actually you need to format the database. Can you do it else this problem will remain.

Comment: You need to start with a new database.

Comment: @JamAndJammies I have updated the answer with a detailed one, which I had told you earlier. It will run very smoothly but for that I think you need to start with a new databse.

Comment: @JamAndJammies, Have you tried the solution?? Did it worked for you?

Comment: no, i had this already. this does not work. would you know how to drop the table completely?

Comment: But this should work, I have tried on my project and it works. Have you checked the updated answer?

Comment: like ive said, i already had this before u posted it. it doesnt work